# why 'xml-not-well-formed'?

Tags: xmpp, sasl

using sasl plain in xmpp

from server (sasl negotiation)

```
<stream:features><mechanisms xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-1</mechanism></mechanisms><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/' ver='TQ2JFyRoSa70h2G1bpgjzuXb2sU='/><register xmlns='http://jabber.org/features/iq-register'/></stream:features>
```

sent from client

```
<auth xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl' mechanism='PLAIN'>AGlnZW55YXIAMTIzNDU2Nzg=</auth>
```

where the crappy thing in between is base64-encoded of "\0login\0password"

respond from server

```
<stream:error><xml-not-well-formed xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'/></stream:error>
```

Any reason? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The First entry has an extra Closing "mechanisms" tag after the SCRAM-SHA-1 Item.

Comment: No, it is not extra. "mechanisms" appear at the beginning.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. Everything else, opening and closing tags all match, and quotes all match. Unless this is validating against a specific XML Schema, and the error is mis-leading, I am not sure what else to check.

Comment: I saw previous posts mentioning sasl plain is not really supported even advertised. might be the case, I guess. I also tried user@domain\0user\0pwd, not working either.

Answer (score -1):

As others have pointed out: The XML looks well formated. I guess you need to rethink your problem. It's not "Why is the XML not well formated", but "Why **does the server reply** with xml-not-well-formated when it sees this stanza?"

And in order to answer this question you (nobody else can do it for you) should debug the server implementation and find out what's causing it.